# Storage Access Framework - Events produced by file operations in folder

Tags: android, file, events, event-listener, storage-access-framework

Is it possible to receive file-operations events happening inside a folder under Storage Access Framework into an Android app?

I mean, a folder that was selected by the user, and thus authorized.

The app has the corresponding uri in a suitable form.

When a file is modified, created or removed inside that folder an event should reach the Android app back, even if this time no operations were performed by the app itself or from the device in use.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can try using a `ContentObserver` for the folder `Uri`, but I doubt that it will work. Outside of that, AFAIK, you are out of luck.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am looking at documentation. It seems that there is a distinction between notifications and self-notifications. It looks promising. At least if the providers do not implement it (I did not test it yet), an official feature/bugfix request could be filed for GDrive, for example.