# SAF - listening to events from a folder in the cloud

Tags: android, events, google-cloud-platform, picker, storage-access-framework

I am experimenting with Storage Access Framework, because I would like to improve my app, that has migrated to SAF already (although I had to surrender some features because of some SAF design flaws or maybe bugs).

Now I want that my app is notified when the user does something in a SAF folder in the cloud.

At present time it is purely experimental because it is by hack that it is possible to have the uri of a cloud folder by GDrive.

(the other cloud providers seem not to be SAF ready, please correct me if I am wrong)

I am just working in advance before they release the full feature (there is a bugfix request about that) to be able to select a folder on a cloud storage root in the system picker.

I created a simple application for creating a SAF folder on the cloud (selection is not possible at present time on cloud storage) and listening to events.

```
package com.example.safevents;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import  com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Activity activity;
Handler handler;
Observer observer;


class Observer extends ContentObserver {

    public Observer(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        this.onChange(selfChange, null);
        Log.d("SAF","event fired; selfchange="+selfChange);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

        Log.d("SAF","event fired on uri="+uri.toString()+"; selfchange="+selfChange);
    }
}

public void openPickerForFolderCreation(Activity activity, int requestCode) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.document/directory");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

public Uri takePermanentReadWritePermissions(Activity activity, Uri uri, int flags) {
    int takeFlags = flags
            &
            (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            );

    ;


    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);

    return uri;

}

public boolean arePermissionsGranted(Activity activity, String uriString) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);


    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    List<UriPermission> list = resolver.getPersistedUriPermissions();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        if (((Uri.decode(list.get(i).getUri().toString())).equals(Uri.decode(uriString))) && list.get(i).isWritePermission() && list.get(i).isReadPermission()) {
            return true;
        }


    }

    return false;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity=this;
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            SAFUtils.openPickerForFolderCreation(activity,0);
        }
    });
}
```

@Override 
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    //important
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
    }

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent returnedIntent)
{
Log.d("SAF","picker returned "+resultCode+" "+requestCode);
if (returnedIntent!=null) Log.d("SAF","intent="+returnedIntent.toString());
if (returnedIntent.getData()!=null) Log.d("SAF","uri="+returnedIntent.getData().toString());

//resultCode is -1
    if (resultCode==-1)
        if (requestCode==0)
        {

            Uri uri=SAFUtils.takePermanentReadWritePermissions(activity,returnedIntent.getData(),returnedIntent.getFlags());

            Log.d("SAF","read/write permissions="+SAFUtils.arePermissionsGranted(activity,uri.toString()));

            handler=new Handler(){};

            observer=new Observer(handler);
            getContentResolver().
                    registerContentObserver(
                            uri,
                            true,
                            observer);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I get this log lines:

```
com.example.safevents D/SAF: picker returned -1 0
com.example.safevents D/SAF: intent=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=3;doc=encoded=randomalphanumericsequence= flg=0x43 }
com.example.safevents D/SAF: uri=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D3%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3Dthesamealphanumericsequence%3D
com.example.safevents D/SAF: read/write permissions=true
```

but I do not receive any event notifications after some simple file operations inside the created folder.

Note that resultCode= -1.

Also note that omitting the call to the takePersistentPermissions method leads to no permissions, resulting from the utility function that check them not finding the uri in the list.

Is there something wrong in the code above?

Is the creation of SAF cloud folder such a hack that it does not work?

Is a further hack possible to force this to work so to be tested roughly in advance?

Is that SAF functionality not available at present time?

Comment: "Is there something wrong in the code above?" -- you should probably be holding onto the `Observer`. It might be held onto weakly by the framework classes, to avoid leaking observers. If so, then your `Observer` may be getting garbage-collected. However, as [I warned you previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730742/storage-access-framework-events-produced-by-file-operations-in-folder#comment103752086_58730742), while this approach is worth a shot, I doubt that it will work.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not practical with Observers, so what should I programmatically do to hold onto the Observer? If this approach is worth experimenting it is necessary to filter out every possible shadowing issue. So what is your suggestion in my code?

Comment: "so what should I programmatically do to hold onto the Observer?" -- hold onto it in a field of `MainActivity`, rather than just a local variable. Once `onActivityResult()` returns, your `Observer observer` in `onActivityResult()` goes out of scope, and it does not appear that you have a reference to this `Observer` object anywhere else, other than the implied reference inside the framework from your `registerContentObserver()` call. And that reference might be a weak reference. You might also consider unregistering the `Observer` in `onDestroy()`, just to ensure everything is cleaned up.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, it seems not to work even holding onto the Observer, like you thought, but does that deserve a bugfix or a feature request? I think so. What is your opinion?

Comment: I do not know if there is any expectation of a `DocumentsProvider` implementation to call the notify methods on `ContentResolver`. If there is such an expectation, then probably this is a bug in that particular provider. If there is no such expectation, then you would need to file an OS feature request to have this sort of change notification be added to the SAF protocol.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have to add that I tried also device storage positions keeping the app active in half screen, but when I opened it at full screen a null pointer error was issued about the Observer in onDestroy(), so it could be as weak as to be removed early, and so it cannot communicate events. What do you think?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand that. Note that your activity field is only around for a given activity instance, and configuration changes will destroy and recreate your activity. If your `Observer` field is `null`, that would suggest that you did not register an `Observer` in that activity instance.

Comment: @CommonsWare being as you say, how can I check the device storage positions, I mean, because the app is no more in the foreground when I perform operations in the filesystem by means of a file manager, it could be not responsive to the SAF events.

Comment: You do not have to use a `ContentObserver` with an `Activity`. You could use one with a foreground `Service`. Or you could try using the "trigger" options with `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager` to have what amounts to a `ContentObserver` that works independently of your process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, there are some aspects to be taken into account. Now, still it is strange that the observer variable is null before the activity is destroyed. Could this be a hint about some early disappearing of the Observer, that would prevent it from listening to events?

Comment: @CommonsWare The activity was recreated, then recreated again, so I thought the created folder (on the device) was still the one listened to. But also creating a new folder on the device when the app is half-screen does not provide events. So it does not work. Now it has to be decided whether to file a bugfix/feature request or not. But how to assess that there is the expectation about GDrive providing those events?

Comment: "But how to assess that there is the expectation about GDrive providing those events?" -- try to find more material or samples on `DocumentsProvider`, I guess. I never wrote much about it personally.